# For Facebook Apps, how to call the parent window in the iframe?

Tags: facebook, iframe

So, in facebook, I cannot call myFrame.window  to get the iframe parent window.
How can I do it?

What I'm trying archieve is: I have a popup (div) that will load a iframe.
And then in the iframe will have a button.  Once people click the button inside the iframe, I want to close the popup(div).
Normally, I need to get the parent window.  Then I can destroy the popup div.  But  in facebook, how can I do it? any alternative way to do that?

I don't want to refresh the page. :)

Answer (score 0):

If you can't access the parent from the iframe, you could try sending a function reference from the parent to the iframe.

In your parent:

```
iframe.contentWindow.closeFn = function() { /* destroy popup */ }
```

Then, in your iframe, call `window.closeFn()` when you want to destroy the popup.

The `contentWindow` may have some cross-browser issues, you can read further [here](http://www.dyn-web.com/tutorials/iframes/refs.php)

I have not tried this in Facebook myself - no guarantees it will work there, but might be worth trying.

Comment: Sorry. thanks but it is not helpful.  
Facebook disallows direct access to some functions / variables. e.g. the window object.  

If not facebook, I know how to make it work. :)  thanks.

Comment: I don't think Facebook can do anything about you referring to your iframe's window object from within your iframe though? If they disallow access to iframe.contentWindow, then this isn't useful either.